# Using Spring WS without Tomcat

Tags: spring, web-services, wsdl, spring-ws, command-line-interface

I have written a client (which consumes a SOAP web service)

```
@Bean(name = "foo")
public Jaxb2Marshaller marshallerFoo() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setContextPath("path.to.entity.foo");
    return marshaller;
}

@Bean
public FooConnector getFooConnector(@Named("foo") Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
    FooConnector client = new FooConnector();
    client.setDefaultUri("http://" + HOST_IP + ":" + HOST_PORT + HOST_PATH + "/Foo");
    client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
    client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
    return client;
}
```

`FooConnector` is a class which extends from Springs `WebServiceGatewaySupport`. So far everything works, I am deploying the application into Tomcant and I have no problems. Now I have a new requirement, I want to be able to run standalone Java applications (CLI tools) which also access this web service. I don't want to rewrite the above been definitions. I am looking for a way to reuse these definitions but instantiate a SimpleHttpServerFactoryBean which will automatically be used to access the web service.

According to [this document](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/reference/html/server.html#d4e1003) this is possible, but I am using Annotation based configuration, so I am not sure how to convert this XML specification into annotations. Also what irritates me is that the example specifies the wsdl names which I should not need since I have created Java entities from the wsdl already.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using only the client-side part of Spring-WS, and that has no Servlet requirements. The `SimpleHttpServerFactoryBean` you mentioned is for the server-side. As such running on Tomcat is not required. You should be able to reuse that configuration in a CLI environment without any problems.